# some questions about the usage of Iterator function

Tags: php

Code is from:http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php(Example #1 Basic usage)

```
<?php
class myIterator implements Iterator {
    private $position = 0;
    private $array = array(
        "firstelement",
        "secondelement",
        "lastelement",
    );  

    public function __construct() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function rewind() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function current() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return $this->array[$this->position];
    }

    function key() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return $this->position;
    }

    function next() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        ++$this->position;
    }

    function valid() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
    }
}

$it = new myIterator;

foreach($it as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Output is:

```
string 'myIterator::rewind' (length=18)

string 'myIterator::valid' (length=17)

string 'myIterator::current' (length=19)

string 'myIterator::key' (length=15)

int 0

string 'firstelement' (length=12)

string 'myIterator::next' (length=16)

string 'myIterator::valid' (length=17)

string 'myIterator::current' (length=19)

string 'myIterator::key' (length=15)

int 1

string 'secondelement' (length=13)

string 'myIterator::next' (length=16)

string 'myIterator::valid' (length=17)

string 'myIterator::current' (length=19)

string 'myIterator::key' (length=15)

int 2

string 'lastelement' (length=11)

string 'myIterator::next' (length=16)

string 'myIterator::valid' (length=17)
```

So we can see:
1st, the order of function(`var_dump(__METHOD__)`) output is:

```
string 'myIterator::rewind' (length=18)
string 'myIterator::valid' (length=17)
string 'myIterator::current' (length=19)
string 'myIterator::key' (length=15)
```

2nd and 3rd, the order of function output is:
the order of function output is:

```
string 'myIterator::next' (length=16)
string 'myIterator::valid' (length=17)
string 'myIterator::current' (length=19)
string 'myIterator::key' (length=15)
```

4rd, the order of function output is:

```
string 'myIterator::next' (length=16)
string 'myIterator::valid' (length=17)
```

My question is:

1. there are 5 functions: `rewind();current(); key(); next(); valid();` why some functions seems not execute sometimes? eg, we can not see `myIterator::next` in the 1st function output. and also `rewind()` only shows one time.
2. there are 3 values in $array, so supposed foreach only run 3 times, but we can see `string 'myIterator::valid' (length=17)` appear 4 times, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is the initialization of the `for`-loop. It calls `rewind` to move the cursor to the beginning of the list. That's also why you don't see a `next` there.

The last part does a `next` but then, the `for`-loop realizes that the end of list is reached, because `valid` returned `false`. So `valid` is called 4 times, 3 times returning `true`, then returning `false` once. How would the `for`-loop know where to stop otherwise?